# Getting a REGEX too complicated error when trying to programmatically screenshot a page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, custom-controller, html2canvas

I have a requirement where I have to take a screenshot of multiple pages and store them in documents on the click of a button. I have everything working perfectly on a windows machine. But when I try it on a mac I get a REEGEX too complicated error when trying to screenshot a specific page. I am using HTML2CANVAS to take the screenshot, and then pass the blob value to my controller.

Here is the relevant controller code.

```
    transient public string strImageBlob {get;set;}
    transient public string strImagename {get;set;} 

    public void captureImage()
        {
            folderId = [SELECT ID 
                            FROM Folder 
                            WHERE NAME = 'DOC Folder'].Id;
            Document d = new Document(); 
            d.Name = strImagename+'.png';         
            d.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(strImageBlob.replaceFirst('data:image/png;base64,','')); 
//Error occurs on the above line ^^^^^^^
            d.ContentType = 'image/png';
            d.FolderId = folderId;
            d.IsPublic = true;
            insert d;
            RelateListSnapCntrl.saveRecIdinCookie(d.Id);
            system.debug('\n--d---'+d);
        }
```

The error occurs in the line indicated above. It seems to occur only in a Mac (or possibly in computers with higher resolution monitors). Is there a way I can handle this error?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the EXACT error message seen as part of your question please? Just [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/283748/edit) the question to add the detail.

Comment: if string you are operating on is more than 1 MB, this error will occur

Comment: @PhilW I have added the error msg to the question.

Comment: @cropredy Is there any way I can work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical reason for [regex too complicated is when the target string is > 1 MB](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325937&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

The String class has three methods:

- `someString.replace(target,replacement)`
- `someString.replaceAll(regex,replacement)`
- `someString.replaceFirst(regex,replacement)`

Your application is trying to replace `data:image/png;base64,` with simply `,`

If your application is OK with replacing *all* of `data:image/png;base64,` with `,`, then use the `replace(target,replacement)` method as it doesn't use regex

Example:

```
someString.replace('data:image/png;base64,',',');
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!